# Will my applications disappear after one year?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I want to buy Apple Developer Account for 1 year but I want to know that if I dont renew my Developer Account after one year that my apps will be deleted from App Store?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your apps will be removed from the App Store if you don't renew your developer membership.

Your apps will be removed from sale and will disappear from the App Store.